# Unverified Breakpoint: Apex Replay debugger not stopping at the break points in VS Code

Tags: vs-code, apex-debugger, apex-replay-debugger

I am experiencing an issue with the Apex Replay Debugger on my Mac. When I am trying to replay a log file in Apex Replay Debugger in VSCode, the debugger never stops at the specified break point.

When I hover over the breakpoint when the log file execution starts, it shows the breakpoint as an ‘unverified breakpoint’ attached the image below.

The log file did not skip any execution.

I have specified the Salesforcedx-vscode-apex › Java: Home in the settings as well.
Did anyone experience this before or any thoughts on how I can fix this issue

Comment: Have you reviewed this and does it help in any way? https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1563

Comment: I have looked into it and it doesn't apply to my situation. Still have no luck figuring it out.